# How to fill the screen with video preview on Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, size

I am creating an application for video capturing on a Windows Mobile device. In the MainFrame, there is a menu and status window (custom window). The video size width:height ratio is **4:3** so in the case, there are some other elements on the screen the video doesn't fill the whole area.

This is the function that arranges screen elements:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    ToggleFullScreen(TRUE);
    CScreenOrientation::SetScreenOrientation(270);
    if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(&r);
    if (!m_wndStatus.Create(NULL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
                CRect(0, 0, r.right, TOOLBAR_HEIGHT), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST + 1, NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create status view\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a camera view
    if (!m_wndCameraView.Create(NULL, NULL, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW,
        CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create camera view\n");
        return -1;
    }
    m_wndCameraView.SetLogDirectory(m_Settings.m_LogDirectory);

    if (!m_wndCommandBar.Create(this) ||
        !m_wndCommandBar.AddAdornments(dwAdornmentFlags) ||
        !m_wndCommandBar.InsertMenuBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create CommandBar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    m_wndCommandBar.SetBarStyle(m_wndCommandBar.GetBarStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_FIXED);

    m_QueueProgressData.SetHandle(this);

    // Update GUI state
    UpdateGUIState();

    //VideoPreviewShow();
    
    // TODO: check error
    m_SleepModeTimerID = SetTimer(1, (UINT)1000, (TIMERPROC)CMainFrame::SleepModeTimer);

    PostMessage(WM_CHECK_UPGRADE, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to fill the blank area (the area not filled by status window and menu bar) with video preview without changing the width:height ratio (overwrite a part of video preview with status bar and menu) perhaps with changing the Window Styles flags or any other approach?